# Web Application Request

Tags: c#, web-applications

I have a Web Application Request and a basic exception being thrown if null.

Can anyone recommend something better than a generic exception?  I'm sure my client would like something that either lets the user know the request was null or even forces the request to not be null.

Code Example:

```
public async Task <Lead> BuildLeadFromRequest(object request)
{
        var req = request as WebApplicationRequest;
        if (req == null)
            throw new Exception(); //TODO: Something better than throwing an exception
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all why don't you have `public async Task BuildLeadFromRequest(WebApplicationRequest request)`? If for any reason you can't change it then you may use `ArgumentException` with a proper error message.

Answer (score 1):

A user isn't going to know the difference between the exception types, to expect them to act on a particular `type` is a fools bet, what's useful to a user is a meaningful message, obscure exception names and stack traces are useful only to us, the developers.

Reporting status to a user on an operation thru a stack trace is not a very good idea either, however I can't understand why your method would be called with a null to begin with so this is a critical exception and should be `thrown`.

There are many ways to give more info but the most simple is like this:

```
if (req == null)
        throw new Exception("Request was not valid.");
```

What's missing in your question is how this could occur, your exception detail could state how it's possible.

```
if (req == null)
        throw new Exception("Request was not valid.  Perhaps you did operation A instead of doing expected operation B...  blah blah");
```

Obviously you could create sub classes of `Exception` or `ApplicationException` but that's your call.

Now why this method could be called with a null is another question.

Comment: I agree with this. I'm not familiar with C# (and ASP.NET MVC if that's what OP is using), however OP could possibly just redirect to a 404 page should the argument into the function be malformed or otherwise incorrect.

Comment: agreed as long as there is useful information stating why you are being shown a 404, the biggest issue I have with errors/exceptions is the exception that doesn't tell me anything.  NullRef exception is obvious.. and is actually what this OP exception really is, but there is a big question mark how that could happen in this scenario.